# Docker compose and REST config

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have docker compose service made up of elasticsearch and a nodeJS app that uses elasticsearch. Something like :

```
web_app:
  image: my_nodejs
  links: 
    - ess
  ...
ess:
  image: elasticsearch
  expose: 
    - "9200"
    - "9300"
```

I need to ensure that a particular index exists in my elasticsearch instance. For whatever reason (don't ask), I have to add this index via a rest call to the running elasticsearch container. What is the best way to do this?

I could run a short term job just to make a REST call to create the index, but then I have to do monitoring and dependency work that docker compose does not support.

I prefer the idea of running the REST calls in a script in the ess image. Is that good practice? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Running the create index script as part of the entrypoint script for the `ess` service would work.  I like to do that kind of work during the build phase of the image, but it's a little more work to set that up.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I suppose it makes sense. Longer build time, shorter start up time. I'll give it a try thanks.